# Why does this SPARQL query return certain items as subjects?

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

I have the following data graph:

```
@prefix hr: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sch: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

hr:Another a rdfs:Class .

hr:Employee a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:label "model" ;
    rdfs:comment "a good employee" .

hr:Longer a hr:Employee ;
    rdfs:label "model" ;
    rdfs:comment "a good employee" .

hr:freestanding a rdf:Property ;
    sch:rangeIncludes sch:Text .

hr:missing rdfs:comment "some comment about missing" .

hr:name a rdf:Property ;
    sch:domainIncludes hr:Employee .

hr:nosuper a rdf:Property ;
    sch:domainIncludes hr:Uncreated ;
    sch:rangeIncludes sch:Text .

hr:randomtype a hr:invalidtype ;
    rdfs:label "some label about randomtype" ;
    rdfs:comment "some comment about randomtype" .

hr:typo a rdfs:Classs ;
    rdfs:label "some label about typo" ;
    rdfs:comment "some comment about typo" .
```

The only subjects defined in the triples are hr:Another, hr:Employee, hr:Longer, hr:freestanding, hr:missing, hr:name, hr:nosuper, hr:randomtype, and hr:typo. As proof, when I run the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s 
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .    
}
```

I get the result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| s                                                          |
==============================================================
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#freestanding> |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Another>      |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#typo>         |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#nosuper>      |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Employee>     |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#randomtype>   |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Longer>       |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#missing>      |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#name>         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I execute this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE {
    {

            ?s rdf:type* ?o .    
    }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| s                                                          |
==============================================================
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Longer>       |
| rdfs:Class                                                 |
| sch:Text                                                   |
| "some comment about typo"                                  |
| "some label about typo"                                    |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#nosuper>      |
| "a good employee"                                          |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Uncreated>    |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#missing>      |
| "some comment about randomtype"                            |
| "model"                                                    |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#freestanding> |
| "some label about randomtype"                              |
| "some comment about missing"                               |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Another>      |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#invalidtype>  |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#typo>         |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#randomtype>   |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#Employee>     |
| rdfs:Classs                                                |
| rdf:Property                                               |
| <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#name>         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure why items like rdf:Property, "a good employee", sch:Text, etc. are being returned as subjects when they are not subjects in the data graph.

Why are they?

Clearly, this has something to do with how SPARQL handles property paths which I do not yet understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a property path with a zero-or-more wildcard ('*'). Effectively, the pattern `?s rdf:type* ?o` means "every value `?s` connected through zero or more type relations to any value `?o`".

*Every* value that appears in your graph (in fact every value in any graph) matches that, because every value has at least zero type relations. Therefore, a value like `"some comment about typo"` get returned, because although it never occurs as a subject in your data, it is true that it is a value that has zero type relations to something else.